# What is the name of the sauce which is made of Yoghurt and fresh Cucumbers?

Tags: sauce, indian-cuisine

I had this "Kebab Bombay" in Holland a few years ago, to which belonged a very thick, creamy, slightly yoghurty, very fresh sauce/salat containing fresh cucumbers. Supposedly it was an Indian dish, but that may just have been "inspired by".

[image: Kebab Bombay]
(sauce visible on the left, best picture I could find)

What is this kind of sauce called?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like a Cucumber Raita to me. It's quite a common accompaniment to spicy food as the yoghurt element really helps ease the burn.

Very simple to make and often contains fresh mint along with the cucumber to give it a really cool, fresh taste.

Example recipe here: [Good Food Channel](http://uktv.co.uk/food/recipe/aid/516821)

Comment: You could add a garlic clove if you want.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the Greek Tzatziki sauce to me.

Comment: But the package in the picture says "Bombay". Are Tzatziki's ingredients really the same? It would be great to find if those 2 sauces are the same despite being from different countries/cultures.

Comment: Yogurt and cucumber is a common pairing and eaten across the middle east, eastern Europe, and southern asia (at least the parts where yogurt is common). The Greeks derived their Tzatziki sauce from the Turkish Cacık. The ones I have seen vary a bit in the spices and ratios. The question is certainly about this particular Indian variant and not yogurt-cucumber sauces in general.